# SQL Server nested select in from clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry, for not being clear. My Current query looks like below and is working fine except for certain conditions.

```
SELECT A.*, 
(SELECT .... from Emp where name = A.Name...... ) 
(SELECT .... from Emp where name = A.Name...... ) 
    ........
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, column3 
FROM xxx 
WHERE condition1) A
```

Sometimes, the below query i.e in the from clause gives no results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, column3 
FROM xxx 
WHERE condition1
```

When no results from above sub query, I don't want the below queries to fail due to join

```
(SELECT .... from Emp where name = A.Name...... ) 
(SELECT .... from Emp where name = A.Name...... )
```

1. when the subquery from the from cause returns no results then display everything in Emp table itself without the join i.e without name = A.Name
2. when the subquery from the from cause returns results then display everything in Emp table with the join i.e with name = A.Name

Hence, was trying to add the case statement as below to check if the subquery gives any results. Maybe there is a better way to achieve this.

Please need your help on this.

```
SELECT A.*, 
CASE WHEN exists (select A.*) THEN 
    (SELECT .... from Emp where condition 1...... ) 
WHEN not exists (SELECT A.*) THEN 
    (SELECT .... from Emp where condition 2...... ) 
END Column_Dummy 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, column3 
FROM xxx 
WHERE condition1) A
```

As suggested when I try giving below I am getting error as Invalid object name 'A'

```
SELECT A.* 
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A Where ....) = 0 THEN 'not result'       
ELSE 'you have something there '
END
```

Comment: Not clear. Can you possibly provide some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Your query have big sintaxis errors.  `exists (select A.*)` You cant do that need a complete ` SELECT` with `FROM` and `WHERE` not just reuse the alias

Comment: You have four `from` clauses in your query.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

use a query with `COUNT(*)`

```
 SELECT A.*
       CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table Where ....) = 0 THEN `not result`
            ELSE `you have something there`
       END
```

Comment: Thanks, for responding
if I give this , I am getting error as Invalid object name 'A'.
    SELECT A.* CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A Where ....)   = 0 THEN `not result` ELSE `you have something there` END

Comment: That was just the guideline, you need write the full query.

Comment: How to use A (the subquery) in my example as table name in my example? I am not understanding that. I modified the main post I added above which might be little more readable than earlier. Please need help with this.

Comment: Do you add the `FROM`?? Looks like you dont know much about sql, maybe you should start for the basic.